# iOS 1D/2D barcode scanner library

Tags: ios, barcode

I'm trying to fint the answer to a question that has been asked before,but i still couldn't find the proper answer.

I'm looking for a lightweight free 1D/2D barcode scanner library/api/sdk. I've tried

> zxing

, but its way too enormous,

> scandit

is not free, i couldn't compile

> BXMobile

, etc.

Someone who has experience with barcode scanners could propose me a good suggestion for what i should use?

Thanks in advance!

Zoli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best free one I found was ZBarSDK
http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/

Comment: it says it only supports iphone 3gs and 4 because they have auto-focus. I'm guessing 4s and 5 models are also supported then, right?

Comment: Yep... It should also work with cameras that don't autofocus... but results usually aren't that good.

Answer (score 1):

I've used ZXing before.  If you had trouble with it then use the CocoaPods version...

http://cocoapods.org/?q=zxing

It deals with all the includes and everything.  CocoaPods really is the way forward.

Answer (score 1):

https://codeload.github.com/cgreening/BarCodeExample/zip/master

iOS7 has built in functionality scanning BarCodes not sepearate sdk is required; if your deployment target is iOS7

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results with [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC), which as the name suggests is an ObjC port of ZXing, and which is also on CocoaPods.